# Mysql 8, Query on user table garbles terminal. Is this an Installation issue?

Tags: mysql, debian

I have Mytsql 8.0.1 Community Edition installed on Debian 10.1

Preparing to restore some dump files, I'm attempting to get a remote connection and cannot

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (111 "Connection refused")
```

I was attempting to look at users and see what was there and got this:

```
mysql> select user, host from mysql.user;                       
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| root             | %         |
| root             | tuivhk    |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select user, host, authentication_string from mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| user             | host      | authentication_string                                                  |
+------------------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| root             | %         | $A$005$sH
~m%:G'{a*wGdR.BP9eON1eqM95YlN.1CJB6YeiQbiQ7l33i.wZuD |
| root             | tuivhk    | $A$005$=BLI-+,?)~5,Zh0QZAK-aX/a+N++a+/8BS|+IX+++1+gO/0++Y60y_8ZA |
| +y_-+.i+f-_che+a | +-ca+h-_+ | $A$005$THISISACOMBINATIONOFINVALIDSALTANDPASSWORDTHATMUSTNEVERBRBEUSED |
| +y_-+._e__i-+    | +-ca+h-_+ | $A$005$THISISACOMBINATIONOFINVALIDSALTANDPASSWORDTHATMUSTNEVERBRBEUSED |
| +y_-+._y_        | +-ca+h-_+ | $A$005$THISISACOMBINATIONOFINVALIDSALTANDPASSWORDTHATMUSTNEVERBRBEUSED |
| _--+             | +-ca+h-_+ | $A$005$d(+?aM^81^GZO+|Mg++Zdga4_Da-|UefKWXgyhBB++.DD+RYYDMDG__-+EA |
+------------------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
6 _-+_ i+ _e+ (0.00 _ec)

+y_-+>
```

I could use some assistance figuring out what went wrong here.

Comment: *I'm attempting to get a remote connection and cannot* Client? command line to start? client options? *I was attempting to look at users* locally? *Query on user table garbles terminal. Is this an Installation issue?* This is a norma. `authentication_string` may contain bytes which are treated as control ones by the client.

Answer (score 0):

Before I had this issue, I had to reinitialize my instance due to screwing up the mysql database when restoring backup dumps.

I fixed this issue by reinitializing the database

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo mv /var/lib/mysql old_mysql
mkdir mysql; chown -R mysql.mysql mysql/
mysqld --initialize
```

Right here, here is where there was a problem. During the initial install I choose the mysql password rather than the new more secure authentication method. I wasn't sure how that would impact restoring dumps from a MySQL 5.7 instance.

I fixed the issue this way:

```
ALTER user 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password  BY 'password'
```

I did this for every row that had a `'root'@` user and this fixed the issue.

Obviously, the secured method has some control characters in the authentication_string that should not be directly output to terminal.